# Using the LIKE operator and "greater than" in a Case When expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, case-when

This is for a section in a unit test that I'm writing.

I am trying to say pass if any row in a column contains a certain string. So in words, what I want is "if the number of row that contain astring is greater than zero than pass the test".

I have something like the code below, but it fails saying that `myVariable` needs to be declared. What am I doing wrong?

```
    DECLARE @myVariable BIT =
            (
                SELECT CASE
                           WHEN Count(Description) LIKE '%astring%' > 0
                                 THEN
                               1
                           ELSE
                               0
                       END
                FROM TABLE

SELECT @myVariable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
DECLARE @myVariable BIT =
        (SELECT (CASE WHEN Count(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
         FROM TABLE
         WHERE Description LIKE '%astring%' 
        );
```

I wouldn't recommend a `bit` for this.  SQL Server doesn't really support booleans.  Integers (or `tinyint`s even) are usually easier to work with than `bit`s.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that. I've been working on that for thirty minutes. Thank you!

Comment: @GordonLinoff out of interest whats the downside of using `bit`'s? They do at least enforce 2 values (3 including null).

Comment: @DaleK . . . The biggest one I face is that `sum(<bitcol>)` doesn't work.  More prosaically, I think about all the bit shifting and masking that is needed for the database to use them.  Just unnecessary additional operations.

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
DECLARE @myVariable BIT = (
    SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN Description LIKE '%astring%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    FROM mytable
);
```

This sets the variable to `1` if at least one row in the table has a `Description` that matches the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @myVariable BIT=
     (
      SELECT IIF(ISNULL(count(*),0)>0,1,0) 
      FROM TABLE
      WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Description LIKE '%astring%')
     )

SELECT @myVariable AS myVariable
```